# Blank White Page in Vue.js with input null

Tags: javascript, vue.js, if-statement

I am having problems with vue.js.
I want to show a piece of text if the input is null.
Everything just shows up as a blank white page when I run my HTML page.

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Vue.js Testing</title>
</head>

<body>
   <template>
    <div id="input">
        <span v-if="{{ input1 }} == null"> Empty </span>
        <p>{{ input1 }}</p>
        <input v-model="input1">
    </div>
   </template>

    <script src="vue.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And my JS:

```
var input = new Vue({
    el: '#input',
    data: {
      input1: 'Default'
    },
  })
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be like this:

```
<div id="input">
        <span v-if="!input1"> Empty </span>

        <p>{{ input1 }}</p>
        <input v-model="input1">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are using curly bois inside of a v-if, No curly bois required.

```
    <div id="input">
        <span v-if="!input">Empty</span>
        {{ input }}
        <input v-model="input">
    </div>
```

https://codepen.io/michaelmano/pen/zYNmbjb